# How to use csv converter encoding in ruby?

Tags: ruby, upgrade, jruby

```
require 'csv'
module Expertus
 class Dataset < Array
  attr_accessor :data_type, :udc_id, :filename_suffix

# knows its common_udc_id and data type

  def initialize *args
    CSV::Converters[:non_octal_integer] = lambda { |f|
     begin
      e = f.encode(CSV::ConverterEncoding)
      unless e == "0"
        if e.starts_with? "0"
          return f
        end
      end
    rescue
      return f
    end
    Integer(f.encode(CSV::ConverterEncoding)) rescue f
  }

  CSV::Converters[:non_octal_float] = lambda { |f|
    begin
      e = f.encode(CSV::ConverterEncoding)
      unless e.starts_with? "0."
        if e.starts_with? "0"
          return f
        end
      end
    rescue
      return f
    end
    Float(f.encode(CSV::ConverterEncoding)) rescue f
  }

  CSV::Converters[:string_to_bool] =->(f) {
    ['true', 'false'].include?(f) ? f=='true' : f
  }
  @csv_options = {:converters => [:non_octal_integer, :non_octal_float, :string_to_bool]}
  @data_type = nil
  @udc_id = nil
  @filename_suffix = nil
  super
end
def expected_output_filename
    return "#{@udc_id}_#{@data_type}#{@filename_suffix}.csv"
end
def read_expected_output_file_from_directory! directory
  if directory.is_a? String
    p "Directory/File:::: #{File.join(directory, self.expected_output_filename)}"
    p "@csv_options::: #{@csv_options}"
    csv_data = CSV.read File.join(directory, self.expected_output_filename), @csv_options
  else
    csv_data = CSV.new(directory, @csv_options).read
  end
  csv_data[0].map! { |h| h.to_sym }
  self.clear
  self.replace csv_data
end
```

I am calling read_expected_output_file_from_directory method in my jRuby script like:

```
expected_dataset.read_expected_output_file_from_directory! File.join($session.script_dir, '..', 'expectedresults')
```

It is throwing an error:

["wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1) (ArgumentError)"]

/home/eip/jruby-9.4.5.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/csv.rb:1821:in `read'

Any help is appreciated ? Thanks

What worked in this as suggested by @Stefan & @Ilmari Karonen :

```
def read_expected_output_file_from_directory! directory
  if directory.is_a? String
    p "Directory/File:::: #{File.join(directory, self.expected_output_filename)}"
    p "@csv_options::: #{@csv_options}"
    csv_data = CSV.read File.join(directory, self.expected_output_filename), **@csv_options**
  else
    csv_data = CSV.new(directory, **@csv_options**).read
  end
  csv_data[0].map! { |h| h.to_sym }
  self.clear
  self.replace csv_data
end
```

Comment: `CSV.read` and `CSV.new` expect the options to be passed as [keyword arguments](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Keyword+Arguments). You can [convert a hash to keyword arguments](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Hash+to+Keyword+Arguments+Conversion) via `**`, e.g. `CSV.new(directory, **@csv_options)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Stefan notes](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/137283521) in the comments above, `CSV.read` and `CSV.new` expect the options to be passed as [keyword arguments](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Keyword+Arguments).

You can [convert a hash to keyword arguments](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Hash+to+Keyword+Arguments+Conversion) via `**`, e.g.:

```rb
CSV.new(directory, **@csv_options)
```

In Ruby 2 (and JRuby 9.3) you could [pass a hash as the last argument to a method expecting keyword arguments](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2019/12/12/separation-of-positional-and-keyword-arguments-in-ruby-3-0/) and it would get implicitly converted into keyword arguments.  However, in Ruby 3 (and JRuby 9.4) this no longer happens unless you request it explicitly using `**`.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion @IImari & @Stefan

After updating :  `if directory.is_a? String
 csv_data = CSV.read File.join(directory, self.expected_output_filename), **@csv_options
else
    csv_data = CSV.new(directory, **@csv_options).read`

Getting following error : `["unknown keyword: :Converters (ArgumentError)"]
/home/eip/jruby-9.4.5.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/csv.rb:1601:in `open'
/home/eip/jruby-9.4.5.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/csv.rb:1829:in `read'`

Comment: @ShivamMadan: Curious. The `converters` option keyword should, [of course](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#class-CSV-label-Options), be in lower case, so it's not surprising that using upper case `Converters` would cause the error you quote. But I don't see how you could get that from the code in your question above, unless you also changed something else besides adding the `**`.

Comment: It should not be the culprit. In any case, it looks like _somehow_ your `@csv_options` hash ends up with an uppercase `:Converters` key in it. I'd recommend using either a debugger or some debug `puts` calls to figure out how.

Comment: Figured out. Issue was in another code where I am trying to compare 2 csv files column wise and I was not passing @csv_options as keyword argument. It works now !! Thanks again !!